# Invalid outout when writing to file with java

Tags: java, io, mahout, mahout-recommender

I'm trying to write the output to a csv file but the first values are in this format [image]

I used ObjectOutputStream. Normally the first values should be 1,1,1,2,2,2,3....
Here is my code any ideas please ?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.common.TasteException;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.common.LongPrimitiveIterator;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.GenericItemBasedRecommender;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.similarity.LogLikelihoodSimilarity;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.model.DataModel;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.recommender.RecommendedItem;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.similarity.ItemSimilarity;

public class ItemRecommend {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("data/test.csv");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);   
        try {
            DataModel dm = new FileDataModel(new File("data/rated.csv"));
            ItemSimilarity sim = new LogLikelihoodSimilarity(dm);
            GenericItemBasedRecommender recommender = new GenericItemBasedRecommender(dm, sim);

                for (LongPrimitiveIterator items = dm.getItemIDs(); items.hasNext();){
                    long itemID = (int)(long) items.nextLong();
                    List<RecommendedItem>recommendations = recommender.mostSimilarItems(itemID, 3);
                for(RecommendedItem recommendation : recommendations){
                    oos.writeObject(itemID + "," + recommendation.getItemID() + "," + recommendation.getValue()+"\n");
                    //System.out.println(itemID + "," + recommendation.getItemID() + "," + recommendation.getValue());                  
                }               
            }   
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error !");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TasteException e) {
            System.out.println("Taste exception !");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            oos.flush();
            oos.close(); 
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You use an `ObjectOutputStream`, which is at first designed to serialize POJOs, to write text; you write a `long` using that. Now, do you actually expect the resulting file to be decoded into text at all?

Comment: What is that screenshot? What am I looking at? Please post that as text, if possible.

Comment: The screen shot is the output in the file 3 comma delimited values. I have issues with first value, @fge  I'm asking for help not critics. Thanks

Comment: That was not a critic; that was a hint. You try and write a _text_ file. Now, look at the javadoc of `ObjectOutputStream`. Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You should try FileWriter or PrintWriter

http://www.journaldev.com/878/how-to-write-a-file-in-java-using-filewriter-bufferedwriter-files-and-fileoutputstream